# Testing creation of associated objects on callback with Rspec on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Trying to wrap my head around rspec and proper testing and having some hard time to do the following properly

Let's say we have three classes like

```
Class User
    belongs_to :company
    has_and_belongs_to_many :roles
end

Class Company
    has_many :users
end

Class Role
    has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

In the User class I have before_create callback that assign the user default 'company_admin' role, if the user is first one to be associated with the company

```
def check_for_initial_company_admin_role
  if self.company.users.count == 0
    self.roles << Role.find_by_name("company_admin")
  end
end
```

How do I properly test in my model spec that the user gets assigned the 'company_admin' role in case he's the first user associated with the company?

---

**UPDATE**
working solution

```
describe "#check_for_initial_company_admin_role" do
  it "sets the first user created to be the administrator" do
    Factory(:role)
    user = Factory(:user)

    user.roles.count.should be > 0
    user.roles.should include Role.find_by_name("company_admin")
  end
end


Factory.define :user do |f|
  f.email { Factory.next(:email) }
  f.password "secret"
  f.password_confirmation "secret"
  f.association :company
end 

Factory.define :role do |f|
  f.name "company_admin"
end

Factory.define :company do |f|
  f.name "foobar"
  f.vat_id "1234"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I would approach it like this:

```
describe "#check_for_initial_company_admin_role" do
  it "sets the first user created to be the administrator" do
    company = Factory(:company)
    user = Factory(:user)
    company.users << user


    user.roles.count.should > 0
    user.roles.should include Role.find_by_name("company_admin")
  end
end
```

An assumption here that may be incorrect is that you are using Factory Girl in your test framework. If not, that doesn't really change the "meat" of this test...just those first lines where you create the company and user.

You could also optionally check the user from the company side of things but honestly that feels like a different test entirely--one testing the association between those models.

The approach I would take is that since this is actually a model test you need to create and alter a real model objects, rather than mocking out those objects. If this were a controller test, I'd mock the models and stub the models aggressively.

I hope this helps and addresses your question. If not, let me know where I'm off base and I'll make another pass at it :) I'm only about a year into rspec but I've found that once I wrapped my head around how to test models vs. controllers I've come to love it.

Comment: OT: please use 'be' when using '>': `user.roles.count.should be > 0`

Comment: That said, you don't need that expectation because it's implied by `user.roles.should include(...)`. Otherwise, this is the same approach I would take, except I probably would have written the spec first ;)

Comment: ah, good point. I often get "confused" about straight boolean relationship expectations. I'll add that to my best practices internal list. Thanks!  And yes, I've learned this year to write the spec, get it failing, implement the code to get it green :) really bought into that approach.

Comment: I don't think this example would actually work. It's creating the user before assigning them to a company. Therefore company will be nil and the callback will blow up when calling `users` on a nilClass.

Comment: Thanks, got me on track. I'm using FG and I wasn't building the user-company associations in a one go and thus the User class callback on before_save would fail because there wasn't company object present. I updated the question to show working solution

Answer (score 0):

Without changing your existing logic, I would test this logic in the user_spec like so:

```
describe User do
  let!(:admin_role) { Role.create!(name: 'company_admin') }
  let!(:company) { Company.create! }

  it 'should be added to the default role when created' do
    user = company.users.create!(name: 'Joe', email: 'joe@email.com')

    user.should have(1).roles
    user.roles.first.should == admin_role
  end
end
```

Note: I would be using something like FactoryGirl for the admin role and company objects to make them reusable.

Your use of the role name to indicate behavior is not ideal. It will likely lead to lots of scattered logic throughout your application where you are finding the role by its name and checking the name with if/else or case statements. I would recommend using Rail's single table inheritance and moving all the admin role logic to a separate class. It will keep the model's logic cleaner and make testing much easier.

Comment: Thanks. The reasoning to use role as a separate entity comes from using Devise/CanCan to control authentication/authorization tasks.